# A efficient way to unpack nested json into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a nested json, and i want to transform it into a pandas dataframe. I was able to normalize with json_normalize.

However, there are still json layer within the dataframe, which i also want to unpack. How can i do it in the best way? I will likely have to deal with this a few more times within the project i am doing currently

The json i have is the following

```
{
  "data": {
    "allOpportunityApplication": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "111111111",
          "opportunity": {
            "programme": {
              "short_name": "XX"
            }
          },
          "person": {
            "home_lc": {
              "name": "NAME"
            }
          },
          "standards": [
            {
              "constant_name": "constant1",
              "standard_option": {
                "option": "true"
              }
            },
            {
              "constant_name": "constant2",
              "standard_option": {
                "option": "true"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Used `json_normalize`

```
standards_df = json_normalize(
    standard_json['allOpportunityApplication']['data'], 
    record_path=['standards'],
    meta=['id','person','opportunity']
)
```

with that i get a dataframe with the columns: `constant_name`, `standard_option`, `id`, `person`, `opportunity`. The problem is that the data `standard_option`, `person` and `opportunity` are json, with a single option inside.

The current ouput and expected output for each column is as follow

### Standard_option

Currently an item in the column "standard_option" looks like:

```
{'option': 'true'}
```

I want it to be just `true`

### Person

Currently an item in the column "person" looks like:

```
{'programme': {'short_name': 'XX'}}
```

I want it to look like: `XX`

### Opportunity

Currently an item in the column "opportunity" looks like:

```
{'home_lc': {'name': 'NAME'}}
```

I want it to look like: `NAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the best way, but I think it works.

```py
standards_df['person'] = (standards_df.loc[:, 'person']
                          .apply(lambda x: x['home_lc']['name']))

standards_df['opportunity'] = (standards_df.loc[:, 'opportunity']
                               .apply(lambda x: x['programme']['short_name']))
```

```py
    constant_name   standard_option.option  id          person  opportunity
0   constant1       true                    111111111   NAME    XX
1   constant2       true                    111111111   NAME    XX
```

`standard_option` was already fine when I run your code